# How to debug Retrofit CONVERSION Errors with a custom JsonDeserializer?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I checked the servers response and it deserializes into a Map without problems.

As soon as I attach my deserializer Retrofit returns a RetrofitError with type conversion, but no other exceptions are thrown even though I set the Retrofit logging level to LogLevel.FULL.

How can I debug my custom deserializer to check where the error comes from?

--

I am getting json from a wordpress blog and deserialize it with this

```
public ArrayList<Post> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    Log.d("WayTrace", "Starting Parsing " + json);
    final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    Log.d("WayTrace", "JSONObject " + jsonObject);
    final JsonArray posts = jsonObject.get("posts").getAsJsonArray();
    Log.d("WayTrace", "JSON posts " + posts);
    final ArrayList<Post> outList = new ArrayList<>(posts.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
        final Post post = new Post();
        Log.v("WayTrace", "JSON posts parsing item " + i);

        post.setPostId(jsonObject.get("id").getAsInt());
        post.setTitle(jsonObject.get("title").getAsString());
        post.setExcerpt(jsonObject.get("excerpt").getAsString());
        post.setContent(jsonObject.get("content").getAsString());
        post.setImageUrl(jsonObject.get("thumbnail_images").getAsJsonObject().get("full").getAsJsonObject().get("url").getAsString());
        post.setThumbUrl(jsonObject.get("thumbnail_images").getAsJsonObject().get("post-thumbnail").getAsJsonObject().get("url").getAsString());
        post.setPostTimeStamp(this.mTstampParser.parseMillis(jsonObject.get("date").getAsString()));

        outList.add(post);
    }

    return outList;
}
```

But even those log commands do not appear in my log.

Comment: Maybe try using Gson and the Gson Retrofit deserializer instead as a workaround? That way it could give you more answers about brokenness.

Comment: This actually is a custom Gson deserializer for Retrofit, could you give me an example of what you mean exactly?